# Install Tomcat on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

How do you install [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) on Mac OS X?

[This guide](https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat8/) looks quite complicated.

Comment: There is an updated tutorial from the same author which is really easy to follow: [Installing Tomcat on macOS 13 Ventura](https://wolfpaulus.com/tomcat/).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`brew install tomcat`

(using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) of course)

Comment: how about specific tomcat version? `brew install tomcat@8.5` does not work

Comment: Try `brew install tomcat@8` -> Installs version 8.5

Comment: `brew install tomcat@8` works great. But is there any equivalent of `tomcat-native@8`? I can find `tomcat-native` which works well with tomcat9, but I cannot find the same for tomcat8.

Comment: how can i find its path in my mac?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to start the server?

Comment: @MehdiGolzadeh To have launchd start tomcat now and restart at login:
  brew services start tomcat
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  catalina run

Comment: @GvSharma `brew ls tomcat[@X]`

Comment: How to completely uninstall? tried `brew uninstall` but `brew list` still shows `tomcat@9`..

Answer (score 34):

You just use `brew install tomcat` as mentioned in the answer above.

Should you want to edit configurations or add a web application to the Tomcat you downloaded in Homebrew, the files (a.k.a. "*kegs*" kept in the "*Cellar*") will normally be in one of the following directories:

- `/usr/local/Cellar/<Your-Tomcat-Folder>` (Intel based machines)
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/<Your-Tomcat-Folder>` (Apple Silicon machines)

(note: the specific Homebrew prefix is stored in the `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX`variable)

Should you want to run Tomcat, you just use the `catalina run` or just do `catalina` and it will show you all the parameters you can use with Tomcat.

---

Alternatively using Homebrew, you could first install services with

> `brew tap homebrew/services`

then start/stop/restart Tomcat with

> `brew services start tomcat`

and so on.

Comment: The configurations will be in the /usr/local/Cellar/<Your-Tomcat-Folder>/libexec folder

Comment: Now `Configuration files: $HOMEBREW_PREFIX/etc/tomcat`[src](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tomcat)

Answer (score 2):

If you want simple **step by step installation process** and customized configuration,Click on below tutorial links:

- For tomcat installation:

[This Guide](http://professionalhacker.in/how-to-install-tomcat-on-mac/)

- To Customize configuration:

[Configuration](http://professionalhacker.in/how-to-install-tomcat-8-windows/#configure)